# Более умная подписка по почте

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Как известно, есть возможность подписаться на уведомления о новых вопросах по почте, задав соответствующий [фильтр](http://stackexchange.com/filters/).

Т.к. письма приходят не чаще чем раз в 15 минут, возможна ситуация, когда вопрос уже прочитал на сайте и после этого ещё приходит уведомление на почту.

Хотелось бы понять, можно ли сделать так, чтобы уже просмотренные вопросы не попадали в рассылку?

Comment: Можно читать RSS, там уже посещённые страницы выделяются цветом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin уведомления о новых вопросах будут приходить? Надо RSS читалку ставить какую-то?

Comment: пример: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds. Я через браузер подписался. Но есть и сторонние читалки. Наверняка хоть в какой-то можно настроить заметные уведомления, когда новый вопрос приходит.

Comment: Подробнее: [Как отслеживать обновления на Stack Overflow?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3187/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow)